# Customize specific UICollectionViewCell(s) within a UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift3, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

My question pertains to being able to add a UIImageView for 'select' UICollectionView Cell(s) but not all of them.

The 'select' cell(s) would have a "boarder" image with the 10x10 UICollectionView.

Currently I have in the UICollectionViewCell the following two (2) attributes that are hooked up to the storyboard

```
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var cellBG: UIImageView!
```

Every cell will have a Label and every cell will have a background.

I am declaring the following:

```
var boarderImage: UIImageView?
```

So that I can assign the 'boarder' programmatically.

I am confused on how/where I should have to configure the boarder image as I want this image to be associated to only the selected cell.

If I do the `cellforItemAt` like so:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! CustomCollectionViewCell

    if (squares[indexPath.section][indexPath.item].isWinner) {    

        let imageview: UIImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 75, height: 75) 

        let image: UIImage = UIImage(named: "glowbox")!

        imageview.image = image

        cell.contentView.addSubview(imageview)

    }

    return cell

}
```

But the issue with doing the way mentioned above; is that when I scroll, the boarder image moves to other cells as the UICollectionView scrolls right to left and up and down!?

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong and how/where I should do this assignment so that the 'selected' cell(s) are always displayed correctly regardless of scrolling the UICollectionView?!

Comment: Please post an image of what you are getting and what you are looking for. It will help.

Comment: cells are re-used, so you need an `else` that removes the border image if it isn't required.  Alternatively, use two different collectionvewcell subclasses; one with the border and one without and then deque the appropriate cell type

Comment: OK, but where do I do that evaluation?! In the UICollectionView class or the UICollectionVeiwCell class?

Comment: I would create two different cell classes, that way you don't need to create/destroy the image views.  Then in your `cellForItemAt` you simply dequeue and return the appropriate cell type.